# How to set serializer custom field in create method of Model Serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm working with a very simple model, but i'm stuck here. I just want the after creating a User, i sent him a Token. i created a custome serializer field. 
here is my Serializer class.

```
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    token = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, read_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id',
                  'username',
                  'password',
                  'token',
                  )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        uname = validated_data['username']
        password = validated_data['password']
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(
            username=uname,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        data = self.get_initial()
        data['token'] = Token.objects.create(user=user)

        return user
```

here is my CreateAPIView

```
class UserCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
```

every time when i POST a request to it, it doesn't response me with token, it always gives response without token.

```
{
    "id": 41,
    "username": "J.Son",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [source code of **`Token`** model](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/models.py#L11), it's defined as

> ```
> class Token(models.Model):
>         """
>         The default authorization token model.
>         """
>         key = models.CharField(_("Key"), max_length=40, primary_key=True)
>         user = models.OneToOneField(
>             settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='auth_token',
>             on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("User")
>         )
>         created = models.DateTimeField(_("Created"), auto_now_add=True)
> ```

hence, **`user_instance.auth_token.key`** will return the corresponding KEY.
According to serializer, you can do that by reffering with **`source`** argument as,

```
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    token = serializers.CharField(
        allow_blank=True, read_only=True, source='auth_token.key')
    # your code


    def create(self, validated_data):
        # your code
        user.refresh_from_db()
        return user
```

**UPDATE**
Why **`refresh_from_db()`**?
In your `create()` method, first you are creating the`User` object and assigns to `user` variable. At that time `user.auth_token.key` will be `None`, because, no `Token` is created yet. Then you are creating a `Token` corresponding to the `User`. But, It will not reflect on `user` variable (no *auto-refresh* functionality there). Hence still `user.auth_token.key` will be `None`. This same `user` object/instance is used in **`to_representation`** method to represent the final data. That's why initially it's didn't showed the `Token`.
The **`refresh_from_db()`** , as the name suggests it refreshes it's values from DB, hence it's got `user.auth_token.key`.

Comment: If i wirte Print( data[ "token" ] ) It displays on terminal, but not in response, problem is not in token generation,

Comment: I also created a LogIn serializer,  there i generate the tocken in Validate method and saving it to attrs['token']), it works fine there,

Comment: Updated the answer. add **`user.refresh_from_db()`** in create method

Comment: Yes it worked, can you please explain what was wrong, and why to do that 
"user.refresh_from_db()"